# Calling a Razor page action

Tags: c#, blazor, razor-pages

When a Blazor Server-Side App is generated in VS2019 with individual user account authentication the following code is created:

```
<form method="post" action="Identity/Account/LogOut">
        <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log out</button>
    </form>
```

Here we have a button that logs the user out. I want to call this same action from my own function but I do not know how to post to a razor page. How can I do that?

Comment: If you don't want to give up passing _XSRF_ token to `OnPost` endpoint in `Logout.cshtml.cs` (as shown in the answer below), try doing this with a little bit of JS Interop:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416343/8644294

Answer (score 4):

You can navigate to the page using [NavigationManager](http://NavigationManager)

See this example code:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Logout">
    Logout
</button>

@code {
    private void Logout()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/LogOut", true);
    }
}
```

And in the `\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\LogOut.cshtml` page you will either need to change the `OnPost` to `OnGet` or add `OnGet` method as below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        await SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
    }

    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

Thanks to Henk Holterman as he stated, you will need to set `forceRelead` parameter true in `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("...", true)`

Comment: You will probably need `NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/LogOut", true)`

Comment: Glad that worked, if that is as expected please mark as an answer for others to notice :)