# How to logout of Blazor server from C# code

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor-server-side

I understand that the Signal R is a problem to directly logout.
Does anyone have a way without pressing buttons, to log out from C# code?

Any way will do.

In my case, the user presses a button. Some data is changed and saved, the user automatically will be logged out.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What are you using for authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your authentication (cookie based, JWT, Azure AD, etc.).
If, for example, you use the Identity Server integrated in the standard template you can call the `/Identity/Account/Logout` endpoint via a POST.

In this case the following code will be executed (your code will differ):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    if (user != null)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User {Username} logged out.", user.UserName);
    }
    if (returnUrl != null)
    {
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

this POST call can be done via JS using JSInterop.

Comment: Thank you Nicola. Your JS plan was the answer to my question. In the solution I changed it a bit, but after I first did your suggestion. Very nice.

Comment: This answer seems to be part of [this blog article](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-logout-page/). (Just in case someone wants to see the whole example).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Nicola his answer, I created a simple solution with Javascript.

I use a button in my example, but you can call the function getMeOutOfHere() in your C# code.

On the razor page

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<button @onclick="getMeOutOfHere">log me out</button>
```

and in

```
@code{...
 public async Task getMeOutOfHere()
  {
     await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("IamOut");
  }
}
```

In LoginDisplay.Razor add on the logout Button

```
id="logoutButton"
```

In the _Host.cshtml

```
<script>
window.IamOut = () => {
    document.getElementById("logoutButton").click();
};
</script>
```

When you press the button, it will log you out like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Dinand's answer, this is my complete solution:

### Summary

When a user clicks the 'Break' button, it will perform some steps and finally log the user out (by the app clicking the Logout button programmatically).
[image]

### Step 1:

Add `app.js` to wwwroot/scripts folder.

[image]

### Step 2:

Add this to `app.js`

```
var app = {};

app.ClickLogOutButton = function () {
    document.getElementById("logout-button").click(); /*logout-button is in Areas/Identity/Components/LoginDisplay.razor*/
}
```

### Step 3:

Register `app.js` in `_Layout.cshtml`

[image]

### Step 4:

Add id to *Logout* button in `LoginDisplay.razor`

[image]

### Step 5:

Call the JS function from wherever you want to Logout programmatically.
As an example, I'm calling it from `TakeABreak.razor`

[image]

### Done! ✅

---

### Extra Information

The way it works is that when Logout button is clicked from JS, it performs a Post request to `OnPost` method in `Logout.cshtml.cs`

[image]

### Full Source Code:

https://github.com/akhanalcs/blazor-server-auth/tree/feature/AddClaimsDuringLogin